# How to solve Swipe back not working on iOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

each time i use a plugin to move to the next page on iOS the swipe back will not work like

```
 Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  Transition(
                      child: Bio(),
                      transitionEffect: TransitionEffect.BOTTOM_TO_TOP),
                );
```

i have use like 5 plugin now swipe back is not working

but if i use this

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (ctx) => Actitvities(),
                      ),
                    );
```

the swipe back works....
but i want to use transition for the page route

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Comment: yes!!!.... i solved it

Comment: could you please answer this question.

Comment: check the answer if it does not help open another question and send me the link...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case.
i was using a plugin and the plugin is using

```
WillPopScope (
    onWillPop: () async {
     
    },
```

so i fork the plugin and remove the willpopscope.
then i add the fork plugin like this to my pubspeck

```
  kittens:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/munificent/kittens.git
      ref: some-branch
```

[full example here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages)